# Show/Hide dive onclick button

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons with different ids. I want to hide specific paragraph when button with similar id is clicked.

Here's my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id").replace('test', '');
        $('.p #'+id+'').hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<div class="gallery">
<div class="picture">
<p id="1">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="2">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
</div>


<button id=test1>Click me1</button>
<button id=test2>Click me2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see if i click button with id "test1" I want to hide the paragraph with id "1". But It's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get rid of the `.p` in your selector:

```
$('#'+id+'').hide();
```

You don't have any elements with a *class* value of `p`.  But, more to the point, you don't need to use any other selector elements because you're targeting an `id` which is already unique.

**Note:** Please also refer to information about [restrictions on `id` values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).  In particular, `id` should not begin with a number character.  (Unless that changes in newer HTML versions?)  While your code, with my above modification, *does* seem to work as intended in my browser.  It may not be guaranteed to work in any given browser.

Instead, however, you can use a letter in your `id` values and achieve the same result.  For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id").replace('test', '');
        $('#'+id+'').hide();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<div class="gallery">
<div class="picture">
<p id="A">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p id="B">This is another paragraph.</p>
</div>
</div>


<button id="testA">Click me1</button>
<button id="testB">Click me2</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ID’s Cannot Start With a Number

Comment: @pedram: Hmm, good point.  Though this code appears to be working, it's not necessarily *guaranteed* to work in any given browser.  I'll include that in the answer.